# C: Cannot write Unicode braille to UTF-8 doc when compiling for Windows

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I have some code that works perfectly fine on Linux BUT on Windows it only works as expected if is compiled using Cygwin, which emulates a Linux env. on Windows but is bad for portability (you must have Cygwin installed for compiled binary to work.) The program does the following:

- Opens a document in read mode and ccs=UTF-8 and reads it char by char.
- Writes the braille Unicode pattern (U+2800..U+28FF) corresponding to that letter, num. or punct. mark to a 'dest' document (opened in write mode and ccs=UTF-8)

Significant code:

```
const char *brai[26] = {
    "⠁","⠃","⠉","⠙","⠑","⠋","⠛","⠓","⠊","⠚",
    "⠅","⠇","⠍","⠝","⠕","⠏","⠟","⠗","⠎","⠞",
    "⠥","⠧","⠭","⠽","⠵","⠺"
}

int main(void) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_MX.UTF-8");
    FILE *source = fopen(origen, "r, ccs=UTF-8");
    FILE *dest = fopen(destino, "w, ccs=UTF-8");

    unsigned int letra;
    while ((letra = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {

        // This next line is the problem, I guess:
        fwprintf(dest, L"%s", "⠷"); // Prints directly the braille sign as a char[]
        // OR prints it from an array that contains the exact same sign.
        fwprintf(dest, L"%s", brai[7]);

    }
}
```

Code works as expected on Linux every time, but not for Windows. I tried everything and nothing seems to get the output right. On the 'dest' document I get random chars like:
甥╩極肠─猀甥iꃢ¨.

The only way to print braille patterns to the doc so far on Windows was:

```
fwprintf(dest, L"⠷");
```

Which is not very useful (would need to make an 'else if' for every case instead).
If you wish to see the full code, it's on Github:
https://github.com/oliver-almaraz/Texto_a_Braille

What I tried so far:

- Changing files open options to UTF-16LE and UNICODE.
- Changing fwprintf() arguments in every way I could imagine.
- Changing the array properties to unsigned int for the arrays containing the braille patterns.
- Different compilers.

Comment: did you try brai as wchar_t?

Comment: Yes, it's the same a an unsigned int, didn't change anything.

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019#type-conversion-specifier. I think you neef to change `%s` to `%S` to get the correct Microsoft-specific behaviour.

Comment: Also, check the return code of `setlocale`. Usually it's safer to do `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` to get the user's default locale.

Comment: Thank you, @rici. Tried both (setting locale to user's default and changing %s to %S) but they didn't work either.

Comment: regarding; `FILE *source = fopen(origen, "r, ccs=UTF-8");` and `FILE *dest = fopen(destino, "w, ccs=UTF-8");`  immediately after calling `fopen()`, insert: `if( ! source ) { perror( "fopen to read .. failed" );`  followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @user3629249 Sure! I handle exceptions on the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tested (with MSVC and mingw on Windows), semi-working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const char *brai[26] = {
    "⠁","⠃","⠉","⠙","⠑","⠋","⠛","⠓","⠊","⠚",
    "⠅","⠇","⠍","⠝","⠕","⠏","⠟","⠗","⠎","⠞",
    "⠥","⠧","⠭","⠽","⠵","⠺"
};

int main(void) {
    
    char* origen = "a.txt";
    char* destino = "b.txt";

    FILE *source = fopen(origen, "r");
    FILE *dest = fopen(destino, "w");
    
    int letra;
    while ((letra = fgetc(source)) != EOF) {
        
        if (isupper(letra))
            fprintf(dest, "%s", brai[letra - 'A']);
        else if (islower(letra))
            fprintf(dest, "%s", brai[letra - 'a']);
        else
            fprintf (dest, "%c", letra);
    }
}
```

Note these things.

1. No locale or wide character or anything like that in sight. None of this is needed.
2. This code only translates **English letters**. No punctuation or numbers (I don't know nearly enough about Braille to add that, but this should be straightforward).
3. Since the code only translates English letters and leaves everything else as is, it is OK to feed it a UTF-8 encoded file. It will just leave unrecognised characters untranslated. If you ever need to translate accented letters, you will need to learn a whole lot more about Unicode. [Here is a good place to start](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).
4. Error handling omitted for brevity.
5. The code **must** use the correct charset. For MSVC, either UTF-8 with BOM or UTF16, alternatively use UTF-8 without BOM and /utf-8 compiler switch if your MSVC version recognises it. For mingw, just use UTF-8.
6. This method will not work for standard console output on Windows. It is not a big problem since Windows console by default won't output Braille characters anyway. It will however work for msys console and many others.

Comment: Now it works like a charm! I guess I was overcomplicating things with wide chars and setting locale, and some of that interfered with correct text-encoding. Text is now correctly translated to braille, but console messages wont show non-standard (english) chars (like ñ, ¡, ¿). Gonna see if I can solve it, but al least the program works as it should now. Thank you!

Comment: Console output fixed with:
SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);
Now everything works as it should.

Comment: @OliverAlmaraz UTF-8 console output is unreliable and may differ between different builds of gcc (e.g. mingw32 and mingw64). If you got it working, great.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Use `wchar_t` and `fwprintf`.  Make sure to save the source as UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding or use UTF-8 encoding and the `/utf-8` switch to force assuming UTF-8 encoding on the Microsoft compiler; otherwise, MSVS assumes an ANSI encoding for the source file and you get mojibake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const wchar_t brai[] = L"⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠭⠽⠵⠺";

int main(void) {
    FILE *dest = fopen("out.txt", "w, ccs=UTF-8");
    fwprintf(dest, L"%s", brai);
}
```

out.txt (encoded as UTF-8 w/ BOM):

```
⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠭⠽⠵⠺
```

Option 2: Use `char` and `fprintf`, save the source as UTF-8 or UTF-8 w/ BOM, and use the `/utf-8` Microsoft compile switch.  The `char` string will be in the source encoding, so it must be UTF-8 to get UTF-8 in the output file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char brai[] = "⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠭⠽⠵⠺";

int main(void) {
    FILE *dest = fopen("out.csv","w");
    fprintf(dest, "%s", brai);
}
```

The latest compiler can also use the `u8""` syntax.  The advantage here is you can use a different source encoding and the `char` string will still be UTF-8 as long as you use the appropriate compiler switch to indicate the source encoding.

```
const char brai[] = u8"⠁⠃⠉⠙⠑⠋⠛⠓⠊⠚⠅⠇⠍⠝⠕⠏⠟⠗⠎⠞⠥⠧⠭⠽⠵⠺";
```

For reference, these are the Microsoft compiler options:

```
/source-charset:<iana-name>|.nnnn set source character set
/execution-charset:<iana-name>|.nnnn set execution character set
/utf-8 set source and execution character set to UTF-8
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn'd know that compilers assume ASCII. I didn't find an option to force UTF-8 on MinGW-GCC which I use. Tried both using wchar_t and fwprintf and adding "L" before the char[] and adding "u8", but compiling with i686-w64-mingw32-gcc didn't print anything in the document. I'll try with MSVC and will let you know.

Comment: Found option -fwide-exec-charset=UTF-8 on MinGW, didn't work neither